# C# Find the Index of an Object in List where Object Parameter x equals Value

Tags: c#-4.0, indexof

I need to find the index value of the object in an object list where the parameter x equals a certain value.

Is there a simple way to do this? I understand the IndexOf function, but how can I apply it to the object parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`List.FindIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int index = list.FindIndex(obj => obj.X == value);
```

> The zero-based index of the first occurrence of an element that
>   matches the conditions defined by match, if found; otherwise, –1.